# Subtracting an array from an integer in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, integer, subtraction

I think I'm having a hard time understanding the code below in MATLAB.
I've expected `A` to be `[3,2,1,0]` but it actually returned `[3,4]`. Why does this happen?

```
numberpoints = 1;
x = 4;

A = x-numberpoints:x;
```

Comment: `x-numberpoints` results in 3. Then the array created is from `3:x` in this case `x` is 4.

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: To get the other result try `A = x - (numberpoints:x);`. This will ensure that the array is created from the variables within the brackets before subtraction.

Comment: The colon operator `:` has a pretty low precedence, all arithmetic operators have a higher precedence. If you want to program MATLAB effectively, study the operator precedence table: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what it's doing:

```matlab
> (x-numberpoints):x % (4-1):4 or 3:4

ans =
   3   4
```

To get your expected output:

```matlab
> x-(numberpoints:x) % 4-(1:4)

ans =
   3   2   1   0
```

Comment: Oh that totally makes sense! Thank you!